# Migrating to Proto DataStore

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm trying to migrate from Preferences DataStore to Proto DataStore but the data is not updated in proto data store. Following is the snippet where I'm hardcoding true value without even checking in preferences data store but it is not working. I tried setting value in runBlocking lambda as well but to no avail. Furthermore, just to be sure I set this value directly from actual code where it is working fine.

```
fun provideProtoDataStore(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context, userPreferenceStore: DataStore<Preferences>): DataStore<UserPreferences> {
        return DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer,
            produceFile = { appContext.dataStoreFile(DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME) },
            corruptionHandler = null,
            migrations = listOf(object : DataMigration<UserPreferences> {
                override suspend fun cleanUp() {
                }

                override suspend fun migrate(currentData: UserPreferences): UserPreferences {

                    currentData.toBuilder().setIsUserAware(true).build()
                    return currentData
                }

                override suspend fun shouldMigrate(currentData: UserPreferences): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
            }),
            scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
            )
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing? Newbie here, so apologies for any incorrect terminology used. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work by returning build version

```
override suspend fun migrate(currentData: UserPreferences): UserPreferences {
                    return currentData.toBuilder().setIsUserAware(true).build()
                }
```